# Examples of categories which appear naturally without objects

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, big-list, education

Regarding the [morphisms-only-definition](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category) of a category (which is equivalent to the usual one dealing with objects *and* morphisms), I would like to ask: Which examples of categories in practice appear naturally as a class of morphisms with a partial composition rule, without an explicit or evident class of objects? Are there examples which really *convince* us that the morphisms-only-definition is natural? This may be a vague question, but in principle I would like to know if there is any pedagogical value in the morphisms-only-definition of a category (apart from its usefulness for e.g. mathematical logic).

I think that there many groupoids which appear only via their morphisms. In fact, the original conception of a groupoid was that of a 'group' with a partially defined group multiplication (curiously, it seems that categories are usually not seen as 'monoids' with a partially defined multiplication). Therefore I would like to favor examples which are no groupoids.

Comment: The first example that comes to mind is monoids: they're defined as a class of "morphisms" with a *total* composition rule, the unique object doesn't appear naturally IMO.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Funny example!

Comment: Yes, and i was thinking at groups, but the OP has already discounted this. I do not think thereis anything better than "monoids with a partial composition"  After all this what categories really are.

Comment: $n$-Cobordisms come to mind as a category named after their morphisms, but I don't think they quite meet the criterion of being most naturally defined without mentioning objects _at all_: partitioning the boundary components into domain and codomain is extra structure on the manifold.